# Expected shell command with expansions to work in Ruby (eg, `ls {Gemfile,Rakefile}`)

Tags: ruby

The code:

```
# In IRB, on the root directory of your typical Rails application
`ls Gemfile`            => "Gemfile\n"
`ls Rakefile`           => "Rakefile\n"
`ls {Gemfile,Rakefile}` => ls: cannot access {Gemfile,Rakefile}: No such file or directory
```

I expected the 3rd line to return `"Gemfile\nRakefile\n"`, since the command works fine when I paste it directly in the shell.

I'm clearly missing something that happens between Ruby-world and the underlying shell process that actually runs, but I don't know what that is.

Comment: The brace expansion is a feature of your shell; the interpretter invoked by Ruby isn't guaranteed to be that shell, or have the same features.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. So I checked ENV to see what interpreter Ruby might be using, and it seems to be Bash (ENV["SHELL"] == "/bin/bash"). Shouldn't that work, then?

Comment: Since this works: `/bin/bash -c "ls {Gemfile,Rakefile}"`

Comment: Only if Ruby is looking at that variable, there is no reason it has to. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brace expansion is a feature of your shell; the interpretter invoked by Ruby isn't guaranteed to be that shell, or have the same features.

[This doc for `exec`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exec) suggests that it always uses `/bin/sh`, rather than looking for anything in the current environment (except on Windows, which has no equivalent). This may be intended to help with security and predictability, as changing this to something unusual could lead to surprising and dangerous behaviour.

On some systems, such as Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is a lightweight shell built to be as standards compliant as possible, so will not include "advanced" expansion facilities such as this.